# Spark - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

After using this command to run my spark application on mobaxterm:

```
/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --class CDR.SQL cdr-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This error occurs:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:713)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 10 more
```

Built with maven (pom.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cdr-maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdr-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-repo</id>
            <name>Apache Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I got a feeling this is because my .jar is missing the DataFrame dependency but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're running Spark 2.0 yet you compile against 1.4. Sync those two.

Comment: No need to give --class CDR.SQL in command

Answer (score 2):

You are using Spark 1.4 and deploying it on Spark 2.0 cluster, where the class DataFrame was removed. Currently, there is only type `DataFrame = Dataset[Row]`. Please change dependency version to 2.0 or change cluster version to < 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Goto "p=Project Setting" --> "Modules" "Dependencies" tab. Change the scope of org.apache.spark:spark_core_2.11 to compile.